# Could not find dependency "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.6.1" in android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to include exoplayer in my project but am getting the following errors
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.6.1

then when I click Install Repository and sync project I get another error

Could not find dependency "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.6.1"

Anyone who can knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! instead of  "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.6.1" it is supposed to be  "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1"

Note there is no "r" at exoplayer:2.6.1